# Function To Return Field from MongoDB Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Node.js. I want to make a function that I can call with the arguments of some base values (to identify the document) and then the name of the field I want the function to return the value of.

My documents look like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
    "phone": "555-0125"
}
```

I want to call the function like this:

```
var phone_number = GetInfo({"name":"John Smith"}, "phone");
console.log(phone_number);   // This should output "555-0125"
```

How do I go about this using the Node.js driver for MongoDB. The documentation suggests I will need to take a callback-oriented or Promise-oriented approach but I have no idea what either of those things mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is the promise syntax that is mentioned in the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find):

```
// Retrieve all the documents in the collection
collection.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
  test.equal(1, documents.length);
  test.deepEqual([1, 2, 3], documents[0].b);

  db.close();
});
```

notice when `find()` is called, it returns a [Cursor Object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) which allows you to filter/select/read the results of the query. Since `find()` is an asynchronous (deferred execution) call javascript has to attach a callback that will be executed when the result of `find()` is resolved.

MDN also has more information about `Promise` objects here for further reading: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

In the case of your code, you could do this:

```
// collection defined above this code snippet.
collection
  .findOne({"name":"John Smith"})
  .forEach(function(doc) { console.log(doc.phone) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [co generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) for this. It is easy to understand how it work.

```
//your function call
var phone_number = GetInfo({"name":"John Smith"}, {"phone":1});

//your function description
function GetInfo(query, projection) {
  //using generator
  co(function*() {
    //connect to db
    let db = yield MongoClient.connect(url);
    let collectionName = db.collection(colName);
    collectionName.find(query, projection).toArray((err, doc)=> {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        //your data
        console.log(doc);
     return doc;
 }
db.close();
}
```

You can also use native callbacks for this if you want

Comment: Hi - I tried this. the document prints fine but the value of phone_number is still undefined.